# How to set background color to the content area in UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am using an `UIScrollView` in my application, my requirement is I have to add background color to the `UIScrollView` but when user drags at the extreme top or at the extreme bottom the area other than the content/out side the content which shows in the scroll view should be shown with different color just like in `UIWebView`. In web view if we drag down at the top or drap up at the bottom it will show default background image/gray color and the web view content background color is diff(default white).Can anyone help me in achieving this.

thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to add subviews to the ScrollView that sit above and below the content. This way, they only appear when the content is dragged up or down.

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -200, scroll.bounds.size.width, 200)];
[topView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[scroll addSubview:topView];
[topView release];

UIView *bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, scroll.bounds.size.height, scroll.bounds.size.width, 200)];
[bottomView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[scroll addSubview:bottomView];
[bottomView release];
```

Comment: I think with bottomView's frame, the y value should be: scroll.contentSize.height

Answer (score 4):

just set backgroundColor.

[scrollview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Answer (score 0):

Add a view for the content and set the color of the scroll view to a different color than the color of the view holding the content.